# How to convert a string to timestamp in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have the following dataset

```
    OPEN TIME  CLOSE TIME
0   09:44:00   10:07:00
1   10:07:00   11:01:00
2   11:05:00   13:05:00
```

But here the timestamps are in string format, how can I convert them to time format?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

to_datetime

```
df['Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OPEN TIME'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
df['Close'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CLOSE TIME'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
```

Comment: What is the .dt.time bit?

Comment: ```.dt.time``` extracts the hour/min/secs part of the date. This is needed since ```to_datetime``` will also introduce year/month/day info.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to convert both columns in a one-liner using `apply`. Try:

```py
df = df.assign(**df[['OPEN TIME', 'CLOSE TIME']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S'))
```

To get the times without dates, use the following:

```py
# assign back to the columns   ---- sometimes, this case throws a SettingWithCopyWarning if `df` was filtered from another frame
df[['OPEN TIME', 'CLOSE TIME']] = df[['OPEN TIME', 'CLOSE TIME']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time)

# or call assign and create a new dataframe copy  ---- this case never throws a warning
df = df.assign(**df[['OPEN TIME', 'CLOSE TIME']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time))
```

This converts each string into `datetime.time` objects. However, because `datetime.time` doesn't have a corresponding pandas dtype, it's difficult to leverage vectorized operations. For example, it's not possible to find time difference between OPEN TIME and CLOSE TIME as `datetime.time` objects (so there's not much improvement from strings) but if they were `datetime64`, it's possible. For example, the following creates `datetime64`:

```py
df1 = df.assign(**df[['OPEN TIME', 'CLOSE TIME']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S'))
df1['CLOSE TIME'] - df1['OPEN TIME']

0   0 days 00:23:00
1   0 days 00:54:00
2   0 days 02:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```